# C# Line Painting Problems

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, line, pen

I need help drawing a line on a WinForm.

The code I currently have is mostly pulled off of MSDN:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BouncingBall
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invalidate();
    }
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        // Insert code to paint the form here.
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, 10, 10, 300, 200);
    }
}
```

}

Currently, this code does not draw anything at all.

Comment: This works. Do you actually have an event handler wiring up the Form's Paint Event to your method?

Comment: and as @PaulG eluded, be sure to dispose the pen when you're done with it

Comment: Try overriding the OnPaint method instead of calling the Form1_Paint event.  You clearly didn't wire the event up.

Comment: Besides vcslones hint (you need to __register__ the event e.g. in the __properties-event page__) you should make sure that your form doesn't happen to have a black background color or else you won't see the black line.

Comment: @Justin, would it be more efficient to continually be creating a Pen object and drawing a shape or should I just use the same Pen object over and over again?

Comment: @palmerito0, typically you'd create the pen object on every draw()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code, as posted, is fine. It renders a black line in the middle of the form:

[image]

I suspect your problem is you don't have the form's `Paint` event subscribing to your `Form1_Paint` method. You can't just put this method there and expect it to get called magically.

You can fix that by adding it to your Form's constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Paint += Form1_Paint;
}
```

Alternatively, you can do this in the designer, which does the same event subscription, it just tucks it away inside of `InitializeComponent()`.

Comment: Yup, that was it. I also want to ask another question: should I be using windows forms to paint the graphics for a simple 2d game that involves a few geometric shapes? Or is there another more efficient method I should be using?

Comment: @palmerito0 I'm not exactly an expert on games, so I can't really say. However WinForms, which rely on GDI, are not hardware accelerated, so you'll see high CPU usage if you re-paint 30 times a second. I'd look at a gaming framework that makes use of DirectX.

Comment: Wait, but isn't DirectX for C++?

Comment: @palmerito0 DirectX is just an API callable from many languages. For example, WPF makes good use of DirectX and there are plenty of managed wrapped around DirectX.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN:

`using System.Drawing;`

```
Pen myPen;
myPen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 0, 0, 200, 200);
myPen.Dispose();
formGraphics.Dispose();
```

Your code actually looks fine, are you sure that method is firing?

Comment: or better yet, use using() statements